# Can the aframe raycaster be customized to look like this

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe, raycasting, webvr

I want to add a dot where the raycaster intersects an object like this one in the picture. I know you can modify the line element of raycaster but I couldn't find a way to add a circle or change the one end of the line.

[daydream raycaster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPdvK.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raycaster is just the tool to find the intersection between some ray and your model. Basically, it has nothing to do with rendering. So you can do the following steps:

1) Add the "spot object" to your model (sphere, circle, complex object);

2) Add the "remote control object" to your model;

3) Add the "ray object" to your model (using line geometry, a prefer buffer geometry);

4) Handle mousemove event and find intersection between the ray from the camera to the mouse position and your model;

5) Update "spot object" position (same onMousemove handler): spotObj.position.copy(intersection.point); (or update geometry accordingly). You can highlight intersection face as well;

6) Update "remote control object" position. Set it's position somewhere on the ray (use vector operations). Update it's rotation according to that ray.

7) Update "ray" object or just recreate it.

p.s. It is possible to add some object directly to THREEJS camera object (as child) to keep object position in sync with camera position.

Comment: How to "handle mousemove event"? That's something I've been unable to figure out.